# Converting HTML files into PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation

I am using the following code to generate a PDF file of the HTML Report

```
String url = new File("Test.html").toURI().toURL().toString();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf");
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.close();
```

I was able to use it on sample HTML files to convert to pdf. But when it comes to my real usage, the `HTML` content consists of various special symbols, like **`&,<,>`**  that can't be parsed by `XML`.

I tried using CDATA, while generating HTML itself, but later found that the text around CDATA is not visible in HMTL.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Could you show a sample of a real page? What do you want to get into the PDF, the HTML source or the rendered web page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print to pdf from the browser? Google primo pdf for a program that we'll let you do it.

Comment: This is part of an automation process

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but you can use `StringEscapeUtils` from `apache-commons`. It has methods for escape and unescape `HTML` (you may use them to pre-process your `HTML` before `PDF` generation).

Comment: more precise, mvn: groupId commons-lang, artifactId commons-lang